# Is there a way to build Intu without requiring qibuild?

Tags: watson, intu, project-intu

I'm trying to build the Into sdk but I don't want to install qibuild,  can I still build the sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio you can follow the instructions to build it.

https://github.com/watson-intu/self-sdk

check section

Windows

Set up Visual Studio 2015.
Open /vs2015/self.sln in this project.
Select self-sdk as your startup project, compile, and run.